# Install maven/java packages inside docker image without starting springboot

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN ["mvn", "install"]
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

Which crashes on line 4 (`mvn install`), because all packages are installed, but at the end Spring starts and attempts to connect to the database container (it is not running, because for now I'm only building the images).

Is there a way I can **just install maven packages**, without getting spring up and running? I want to avoid downloading a lot of things every time I start my backend service.

Comment: Can't you just take off the last line from your script if you don't want springboot to run?

Comment: `mvn install` is starting spring. I want it to start only when I decide to run the docker container. That is, when the `CMD` line runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `mvn install -DskipTests`. It will skip everything and just download packages

Comment: Didn't started SpringBoot on step 4, but also didn't cached the packages :/
Everytime `mvn spring-boot:run` is run, packages are downloaded from 0

Comment: Everytime you build an image, you need to always download dependencies. Possible Solution is create a docker image which has all the maven dependencies already there and use that as the base image. From then, everytime you do mvn install it won't download anything from the internet but use the cached one. Drawback is if you end up changing any of the maven dependencies, they will again need to be downloaded from the internet

Answer (score 0):

`CMD mvn spring-boot:run` will cause application to start. Just replace it with a `CMD sh -c` or something that fits your need.

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
>   instruction as well.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/